# Warning: mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I have a php script that updates a database table as soon as i fill up a form through localhost. I am able to access my localhost homepage and then fill up the respective form, but as soon as i hit submit, i get the above error. When i check for the wamp icon that time, it turns form green to orange. This is creepy, it is green all the time but as soon as that particular php file is called, it turns orange. There is nothing wrong with the script cuz i had used it many times before. I had to reinstall wamp in betweeen and its giving error since then.

Also, phpmyadmin page does not open everytime, it says #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server many times. Maybe this is the reason, my php script cannot connect to the MYsql server, i have tried solutions from other threads but none of them in working :( :(

Please help me i am stuck and have an important work to do. Is anybody willing to help me out with temaviewer?

Comment: Can you add some relevant lines from both your MySQL and PHP error-logs?

Comment: Apparently your mySQL-Server crashes. There has to be a reason for this to happen. your mySQL logs should give you a hint or two.

Comment: How do i check the logs?

Comment: Cant make any sense of the logs :(

Comment: 130316 12:29:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130316 12:29:17 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

they are set to default at 60 seconds and this caused my problem.
see here for more [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)